# $('#id').attr('aria-expanded') === true) not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sorry if not seeing a minor mistake, but I cannot get my code to work as I wish.

First: Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wu3xrLgh/3/). (Maximise the result-window to see the problem better).

Click on any of the buttons. Then click the other button. Works as I intended.

The problem occurs when I click the same button twice. The area collapses (as intended), but the other button expands his width.

I tried the following:
*Don't do anything, when the area is expanded.*

If you have a look at the js-part:

```
 else if ($(this).attr('aria-expanded') === true)
```

It does not evaluate true, even when the console logs the property

```
 console.log($(this).attr('aria-expanded'))
```

as `true` and `false`, and the debugging tools shows the property and the toggle when clicking.
[image]

Please tell me if my if-logic is flawed, or if I do not access the `aria-expanded` property correctly.

To rephrase or sum up my problem again:

**If I click a button twice in a row, I do only want to toggle the area, but not the width of the buttons.**

I am open to any suggestions involving a check for other properties than `aria-expanded`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`attr()` returns a string:

```
else if ($(this).attr('aria-expanded') === 'true')
```